# unable to boot to network mode in pi4 B board when SDcard is removed

Tags: pi-4, boot, boot-issues, bootloader, pi4-eeprom

I am trying to Boot pi4 Board in Network boot without Sdcard for that i have done below steps

1 > sudo rpi-eeprom-config --edit and set as below

```
BOOT_ORDER=0xf21 - **Try SD first**, followed by **NETWORK then repeat**
```

2 > vcgencmd bootloader_config - > confirmed its set to 0xf21

3 > poweroff and removed SD card from SD card slot

4 > powerON

Observed boot order is set to 0x41 automatically , please guide me on how to boot **without SD card** in SD card Slot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to Switch to Network boot for Pi4 B board be below Steps :

1 > Set EEPROM to Latest Version by setting in UI by command sudo raspi-config
2 > Set BOOT_ORDER=0xf21
3 > Set TFTP_IP=192.168.50.101 (server TFTP IP can be set any by user)
4 > Remove all files from /boot folder
5 > Reboot

the Client Device will Switch to Network boot as BOOT_ORDER=0xf21

0xf21

2 - Network mode Boot ( second priority from right to left)
1 - SD card Boot (first  priority from right to left)

Comment: if we want to switch to network boot mode without deleting files inside /boot then remove SD card and set BOOT_ORDER=0xf12 and restart after inserting SD card